# bind JSON data to action arguments

Tags: json, grails, data-binding

My Grails app includes an action that expects the following JSON data to be sent via HTTP POST

```
{email: 'foo@bar.com'}
```

Currently I retrieve the value of the email like so

```
def foo() {
    def json = request.JSON
    String email = json.email

    // remainder of action omitted          
}
```

If the data were being sent via URL parameters instead, I could bind it by name to an action argument like so:

```
def foo(String email) {

    // remainder of action omitted          
}
```

Is it possible to bind JSON in the request body to action arguments directly, or is this facility limited to URL and form parameters?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately the binding of method/action parameters is limited to post/query string parameters and does not support obtaining them via JSON or XML.

The next best solution is to encapsulate/bind the request with a command object.

(I tested this in Grails 2.4.2).